# Reserved value in a JavaScript variable is overwritten each time function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, plotly

I need to add a feature to Surface plots of Plotly. Feature is to change the range of Z axis data. problem is that it is only possible to limit the z axis value and expanding the values will not work. e.g. if I initialize 'Z Max' with 300 everything is fine but going back to 350 will keep the previous value. Although I have 'z_data' as my reference value that upon call of function by event listener should reserve the initially existing data, this does not happen and its values are updated to previously assigned 'Z Max' value.

```
Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv', function(err, rows){
function unpack(rows, key) {
  return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
}

var z_data=[]
for(let i=0;i<24;i++) {
  z_data.push(unpack(rows,i));
}

var allData = [];

for (let i=0; i<z_data.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<z_data[i].length; j++) {
    allData.push(z_data[i][j])   
  }
}

var max = Math.max(...allData);
var min = Math.min(...allData);

setPlot(min, max);

function setPlot(zmin, zmax) {

console.log(z_data)
var newZData = z_data;

console.log('min specified: ' + zmin)
console.log('max specified: ' + zmax)

for (let i=0; i<newZData.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<newZData[i].length; j++) {
    if (newZData[i][j] < zmin) {
        newZData[i][j] = zmin
    }
    if (newZData[i][j] > zmax) {
        newZData[i][j] = zmax
    } 
  }
}
  var data = [{
             z: newZData,
             type: 'surface'
          }];

  var layout = {
    title: 'Mt Bruno Elevation',
    autosize: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    margin: {
      l: 65,
      r: 50,
      b: 65,
      t: 90,
    }
  };
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
}

var zMin = document.querySelector("#zmin");
var zMax = document.querySelector("#zmax");

function updatePlot(){
    setPlot(parseFloat(zMin.value), parseFloat(zMax.value));
}

zMin.addEventListener('change', updatePlot, false);
zMax.addEventListener('change', updatePlot, false);
```

Easier with JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mwbbcyja/484/

Comment: `var newZData = z_data;` instead of referencing you should make a deep copy of `z_data` here. And you can incorporate the limiting in that, too: `var newZData = z_data.map(row => row.map(v => v>zmin? v<zmax? v: zmax: zmin));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect :) I'm new to stackoverflow, how could I reward you? @Thomas

Comment: learn, adapt, evolve ... get better. don't just copy-paste

Comment: yeah I definitely would like to learn. I'm new to programming and JavaScript. I assume the code you have written is of es6 features. I would be glad if you can introduce resources for better understanding it.